# Icons don't show up in Tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

i try to make a custom styled list editable with tinymce.
The list-items have Material-Check-Icons as bullet-points. I add the checkicons as css-pseudo-elements `::before`. This works fine but if i add tinymce (v5) to the list to make it editable, the icons disappear. How can i show the list-icons within the tinymce content?
... I already tried to add the material-icon-library to the content_css.

```html
<div id="editable">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editable',
  inline: true,
  content_css: ['https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons']
})
```

```css
#editable ul{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#editable ul>li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#editable ul>li:before {
  content: "check";
  font-family: Material Icons;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #3770d6;
}
```

Here i made a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/-misc-/pen/MWWRjPj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be issue with CSS content:" ". 
But Here's the fix I did on you can get it done with unicode.

```
.custom-list>li:before {
  content: "\e5ca";
  font-family: Material Icons;
  }
```

Link to codepoints in GitHub repository: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints)

I don't know if you get my point or not.